# C# - in ListView's large icon view I cannot update icons properly

Tags: c#, listview, icons

I am using ListView's large icon view, to view database inserts with image per insert.
When a new insert is made, I clear the whole ListView and add all inserts using the following code. It works perfectly, only when run for the first time.
The second time (after a new insert is added), I get all the items, but with missing images (some of them are missing and some of them are scrambled)

```
private void updateListView()
{
    myListView.Clear();
    myListView.Items.Clear();
    myConnection.connect();
    List<String> myValues = myConnection.getMyValues();
    List<String> myImages = myConnection.getMyImages();
    ImageList myImageList = new ImageList();
    myImageList.ImageSize = new Size(256, 256);
    myImageList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
    for (int i = 0; i < myValues.Count; i++)
    {
        myListView.Items.Add(myValues[i]);
        myListView.Items[i].ImageIndex = i;
        myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(myImages[i]));
    }
    myListView.LargeImageList = myImageList;
    myConnection.close();
    myListView.Refresh();
}
```

I've checked with debug and the values/filepaths are correct.

Comment: I am lost, what is churchListView?

Comment: sorry for the churchListView. It was myListView. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:
The problem was that I had the Sort property of the ListView on.
This means that the ListView sorted it's Items automatically.
So in these lines:

```
myListView.Items.Add(myValues[i]);
myListView.Items[i].ImageIndex = i;
```

An item is added and after that the last item (i) is attached to the last image (i)
In between these lines the newly added item is auto-sorted alphabetically, so it isn't
indexed at i anymore, but something else. So the image is assigned to a random item.
Instead I did this:

```
ListViewItem lastAddedListViewItem = myListView.Items.Add(myValues[i]);
lastAddedListViewItem.ImageIndex = i;
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try associating the myListView first before you add the new item:

```
myListView.LargeImageList = myImageList; ,
```

then add item...

```
myImageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(myImages[i]));
```

also what is churchListView..??? where are you declaring it.. if so replace the code example to fit the churchListView or the appropriate ListView variable...